# Change background color for a particular index cell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table with number of cells, with each cell having one `UIButton`. When I click on that button the button cell background color should change. Here is my partial code for your understanding.

When I click on this button all my tableview cells background colors are getting changed. How to do it only for the selected cell?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    cell = (MenuCell *)[menuTableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        [cell initState];

        // Listens for method calls on cell
        cell.delegate = self;
    }

    if ((self.TempArray.count != 0)) {
        for (int i=0; i<TempArray.count; i++) {
            if ([self.TableviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == TempArray[i]) {
                if (cell.backgroundColor != [UIColor lightGrayColor]) {
                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                }

                UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                button.tag=indexPath.row;
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
                [button setTitle:@"UnHide" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                button.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 20.0, 160.0, 40.0);
                [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
            }
        }
    }

    // Set index for this cell (it could be wrong if cell is re-used)
    cell.downloadIndex = (int)indexPath.row;

    Download *download = [TableviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.downloading = download.downloading;
    cell.completed = download.completed;
    cell.MenuLang.text = download.name;
    cell.downLoadPrgView.progress = download.percentageDownloaded;

    // Check for completed status
    cell.completed = download.completed;
    cell.CompletedMenuLang.text = download.name;

    return cell;
}

-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSLog(@"I Clicked a button %d",sender.tag);
    int row = sender.tag;
}
```

Comment: please try cell.contentview.background = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; and make sure that your custom cell background is clear color

Comment: I tried it happens for the cell.. i dont want to change the color for all.. I just need to change the color for the particular cell which button being selected

Comment: Except the particular cell other cell colors are changed..

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of `TempArray`?

Comment: Hi TempArray is for storing the deleted cells in the tableview. When doing undo it should take the values from temparray and give it back to the original position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement below code, you can change background colour of particular cell as well as hide the selected button.

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
    Friends1TableViewCell *cell = (Friends1TableViewCell *)[self.tblVW cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    sender.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: if I scroll the tableview the red color will Stay /Hold or not

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(IBAction)BTNTapped:(UIButton *)sender
  {
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                           toView: menuTableview];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIP = [menuTableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

}
```

do change using this indexpath of cell

Comment: Thanks dude. I got the answer. I need to hide the same clicked button on the particular cell. How can i do for that??

Comment: am not getting u, u want to hide button which button is selected

Comment: Ya every cell having buttons. When i click the button the button should hide and the cell background color should change

Comment: Cell background change done.. But how can i hide the pressed btn in the cell

Comment: for that you have to make a global refernce of button, or else make loop on selected content view of cell and make condition if subview class == button class, than hide tht button

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer..

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"I Clicked a button %d",sender.tag);



    int row = sender.tag;

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];


    UITableViewCell *cell = [menuTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: one question are your sure  , if I scroll the tableview , the `whiteColor` will stay

Comment: no it will not stay. because you are using dequee, you have to store tht index  path in array, and you have to check it in cell for row at indexapth , if array contain indexpath , then white, else what you want to do

Comment: Asad ali. I tried the above answer which was posted by you. It is working fine

Comment: I know that deque cell wont give right indexpath.. so am using your answer. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger selectedRow;

self.selectedRow = -1;          // init with -1


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // ...

    if(self.selectedRow == indexPath.row) {
        cell.backgroundColor = SELECTED_COLOR;
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = NORMAL_COLOR;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender {

    // ...

    self.selectedRow = row;
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```